Получить свойство "На пути есть плохая дорога" в Yandex.Map API
Есть ли способ получения свойства маршрута "на пути есть плохая дорога" при создании маршрута в Yandex.map API? При построении маршрута использования навигатор Yandex есть такое предупреждение.

С помощью API нельзя понять, плохая ли дорога на построенном маршруте. Более того, одной из задач маршрутизатора является обход плохих дорог.

Спасибо! Да, я знаю, что маршрутизатор умеет обходить плохие дороги. Но, есть маршруты, которые без этого не обходятся. Очень жаль, что такой параметр нельзя получить.
